# improve current time complexity

Tags: javascript, maps, time-complexity

I was given this problem in an interview. I was able to do it with a nested loop approach. I was wondering if there is a better way to do this?

APIs given - getFriends(person): it returns the number of friends for the person.
           - getItems(person): it returns the items bought by the person.

Problem: return the list of items which were bought by a person's friends from most bought to least bought.

```
function getList(person)
{
    var itemsMap = {};
    var friends = getFriends(person);
    for(var i = 0 ; i < friends.length; i++)
    {
       var items = getItems(friends[i]);
       for(var j = 0 ; j < items.length; j++)
       {
         if(!itemsMap[items[j]])
             itemsMap[items[j]] = 1;
         else
             itemsMap[items[j]] = itemsMap[items[j]] + 1;
       }
    }

    var res = [];

    itemsMap.sort();

    for(item in itemsMap)
        res.push(item);


    return res;
}
```

Comment: Well as posted your code won't work because `itemsMap` is an object, and plain objects don't have a `.sort()` method.

Comment: itemsMap do not have sort method.

Answer (score 1):

The bottleneck in your code is not the double loop. You have to go over all items, and this is exactly what you do.

The bottleneck is sorting, which might be `O((n*m)log(n*m))` - where `n` is the number of 'friends' and `m` is the average number of item per friend.

This can be done however in `O(n*m)` by choosing a wise sort ([bucket sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucket_sort), for example) or even sorting the elements as you build `itemsMap`.

The reason why you can get better performance than general case sorting is that the size of each item is limited, and the sum of all these items is  at most `n*m`.